# I want to save a Python file with values, but when I save it, the value None is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv
import datetime
#
try:
  Item_price = int(input("Enter the price of the item:"))
  The_number_of_goods = int(input("Enter the number of items:"))
  in_stock = int(input("In the current stock?:"))
  price = Item_price * The_number_of_goods
  current = in_stock - The_number_of_goods
  n1 = print("price")
  n2 = print("current")
  error = True
  time = datetime.datetime.now()
  name = input("Enter Name:")
  file1 = open(name, "a")
  file1.write(str(time))
  file1.write("\n")
  file1.write(str(n1))
  file1.write("\n")
  file1.write(str(n2))
except ValueError:
  print ("Error Please enter a valid number!!")
  error = False
```

> The result::
>
> 3/22/2021
>
> none
>
> none

I want to save a Python file with values, but when I save it, the value None is displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhgKN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZb1.png)

Comment: What is inside `o2`?

Comment: Sorry o2=in_stock

Comment: I tried your code and everything was written to file without problems. Can you provide some sample inputs?

Comment: ran your code and the values write out to my file.

Comment: Of course...I will add a picture

Comment: Also you need to add the datetime library `import datetime`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhgKN.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZb1.png

Comment: I'm very confused, I tried those exact inputs and still everything is ok. If you print `price` and `current` inside the program, what do they contain?

Comment: In your second screen shot your not assigning the value not assigning price to N1, but your printing the price and returning the print vlaue to n1, but print doesnt return anything so n1 and n2 get set to none. either write the price to the xml or assign price to n1 not the result or printing the price

Comment: Do you want a way to send you the code file .. I'm new to this site

Comment: The code you posted to the site works, you have a different local version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import csv
import datetime
#
try:
  Item_price = int(input("Enter the price of the item:"))
  The_number_of_goods = int(input("Enter the number of items:"))
  in_stock = int(input("In the current stock?:"))
  price = Item_price * The_number_of_goods
  current = in_stock - The_number_of_goods
  print("price: ",price)
  print("current: ",current)
  error = True
  time = datetime.datetime.now()
  name = input("Enter Name:")
  file1 = open(name, "a")
  file1.write(str(time))
  file1.write("\n")
  file1.write("PRICE: "+str(price))
  file1.write("\n")
  file1.write("STOCK: "+str(current))
except ValueError:
  print ("Error Please enter a valid number!!")
  error = False
```

The code in your post works, it is different from the screenshot posted.
In fact, in the screenshot, you wrote n1 and n2 in your file which didn't return any value, because it's a print function. In the code above I just added a "Price: " and "Stock: " so that you can read your output file better.